# How to automatically mount swap partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab

I didn't use a swap partition during installation so now that my ubuntu is installed, I used GParted Partition Editor to create an unallocated partition which I formatted as linux-swap. It didn't automatically mount so I right clicked it and selected swapon. Now, whenever I boot the laptop, the partition is not mounted automatically. Swapon still works but if the partition isn't mounted at boot, its as good as useless. 
I saw some answers which said to edit some file named Fstab, but I'm not sure about what changes to make... Please help me  by giving step-by-step instructions as I'm a **TOTAL** noob and don't know U of Ubuntu, I'm having a lot of problems... please help me! :'( :(
Here's what my fstab file contains-

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=33a0fc77-06b0-406c-95fd-15bf7033b619 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo blkid`. It will show the UUID of the swap partition, and we can then add it to /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is your previous `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=33a0fc77-06b0-406c-95fd-15bf7033b619 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Now, to add your swap partition to it, do the following:

1. Open Gparted.

   [image: Gparted screenshot]
2. Right-click on the swap partition and click on **Information**.

   [image: select partition in Gparted]
3. Note down your UUID.

   [image: UUID in partition info]
4. Now, modify your previous `/etc/fstab`, by doing the following:

   - Open the file by typing the command:

     ```
     sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
     ```
   - Then, add this line,

     ```
     UUID=THE UUID YOU OBTAINED FROM ABOVE none       swap   sw         0     0
     ```

     after the line

     ```
     # a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
     ```
   - Save the file and restart your computer. Everything should be working now.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot! You're a god... But hibernate and is still not working. I have 2gb RAM and 3gb swap.

Comment: @HrijulBhatnagar - The question was only about `swap` so, I answered it at that. If you want to know how to hibernate, then, please ask  a new question and share the link in this comment section, I will answer it for you. Also, if the answer helped, then PLEASE ACCEPT THE ANSWER AND UPVOTE IT.

Comment: I did upvote it but since I'm a new user, it says that I need a reputation of 15 to publicly display my vote...

Comment: @HrijulBhatnagar - If you want the answer to be accepted then click on the tick below the upvote downvote buttons.

Comment: And regarding hibernation please ask a new question and link that question in the comments here, I shall try to answer that for you.

Comment: I'm over hibernation now... you can help me with this though-
http://askubuntu.com/questions/712002/how-to-get-back-unity-greeter

Comment: Better to do `mount -a` before rebooting; just validate that there is no error (e.g., typo) when editing fstab.

Answer (score 7):

Type in terminal:

```
gnome-disks
```

Then select the swap partition. In the settings menu select *"Edit mount"* option.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick way that is:

1. Go to Disk from App list
2. Select swap Location
3. Click on the setting
4. Edit mount option
5. Tick at mount at Startup

***below image links are for hint***

[select swap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUiTZ.png)

[click on setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwQf1.png)

[edit mount option  check on mount at start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UlQR.png)